# How to handle async data coming to react components through componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I've been working with redux actions to get data like this:

example:

```js
export const example = () =>  dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_LOADING" });

  return axios.get('/admin').then(({ data: exampleData })) => 
           dispatch({ type: "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: exampleData })
          .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_FAILED", payload: err }))
}
```

and Reducer Example:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    exampleData: []
};

case "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_LOADING":
        return { ...state, loadingData: true };

case "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_SUCCESS":
    return {
        ...state, exampleData: action.payload, loadingData: false
    }
case "FETCH_EXAMPLE_DATA_FAILED":
    return {
        ...state,
        fetchError: 'some nonsense about an error!',
        loadingData: false
    }
```

the problem is when I get the data as probs and want to render it with componentDidMount() I do this:

```js
handleFetchData() {
    if(this.props.assets.fetchError) {
        return (  
           <h1>{this.props.assets.fetchError}</h1>
        );
    } else if(this.props.assets.loadingMovies) {
        return (
            <div className="loading">
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return the data!
    }
}
```

and this seems to work perfectly fine first time logging to the page but when I try to navigate to the page from other pages it gives me an error saying that it can't fetch an undefined data.

I've also tried some other suggestions made by people in stackoverflow like:

```js
fetchMovieResults() {
    const {assets} = this.props;      

    if (assets) {
      if (assets.fetchResultsError) {
        // if error
        return (
          <div className="loading">
            <h1>{assets.fetchResultsError}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      } else if (assets.SearchResult && assets.SearchResult.Search && assets.SearchResult.Search.length > 0) {
        // if data and more than 0
        return assets.SearchResult.Search.map(movie => (
            <div className="latest-admin" key={movie.Title}>
                <div className="poster" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${movie.Poster})`}}></div>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.chooseMovie(movie.imdbID, this.props.formValues, this.props.history)}>Choose Movie</button>  
            </div>
        ));
      }
    }

    // no error or data
    // has to be loading
    return (
      <div className="loading">
         <h1>Loading...</h1>
      </div>
    );
}
```

but that left the data hanging on loading forever and not actually rendering! any suggestions? :)

Comment: can you post your full component here ? I want to have look at the way you are using `handleFetchData` in your `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @PranayTripathi I'm not using handleFetchData inside the componentDidMount.. I'm firing the action in it then using it at a dev.

Comment: Can you paste the complete text of the error you're referring to by "can't fetch an undefined data?"

Comment: @stone 'this.props.assets.data.map is not a function'